# Can send email only the first email of the loop from Microsoft Server 2008 R2 (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, windows-server-2008-r2

I've tried to send email from the query using foreach loop.
It can send only the first occurrence email form the db and the rest are not sent neither.

How can I make them sent???

I use CodeIniter with Microsoft Server 2008 R2.

Comment: We'll need the relevant code to look at.

Comment: Without code we can't just guess.. it can be either broken logic in your code or wrong configuration somewhere on the road..,

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you using forloop to send the email please clear the email state before sending

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```